# (PL/SQL) Crash when I create a new database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, crash

I have a problem with PL/SQL (64bit).

I have a work to do for my school and they give us a data base pre-created, but the problem is that when I'm running the Database that they give to us, PL/SQL crash !

This is because the Database have 8'897 lines.. and I don't know how can I run the script without this *bug*. When I'm running the script line by line it's working, or if I run block by block (of 500 lines) it's working, otherwise I can't run the full script in once.

The problem is not the script ! It's working on school computer or my gaming computer, but not on my Laptop (i7, 8ram, ssd, etc... a good computer).

Is there any option that I can activate to fix this ?

Comment: Which database is it? PL/SQL I know is a *procedural extension to structured query language*; it is not a database. What do you mean that "database has 8897 lines"? Databases don't have *lines*; that looks like a script with that many lines, part (or all) of them being PL/SQL. What does "it crashes" mean? Any error? If so, which one?

Comment: I'm using PL/SQL on Oracle11g. The Database is the script, look I took a picture (https://ibb.co/CvyHBBj), I'm french I don't know all terms in Anglish I'm sorry.

Comment: No, there is no errors, PL/SQL just stop working and Windows is asking if I want to report the error. It's just stop to work.

Comment: OK, Oracle it is. Which tool do you use to run that script? How do you do that? If possible, spool its execution into a file so that we could see what's going on. Or,  at least, screenshot of the last few lines (which show the moment your program crashes). Generally speaking, it shouldn't fail that way ...

Comment: I'm using PL/SQL (last version) to run that script. Here what's going on (https://ibb.co/RpTzVdH)

Comment: Aha, it is the PL/SQL **Developer** (a tool; not a language). Which operating system is installed on that laptop? Do you use the same OS on the *gaming computer*? What happens if you set its compatibility mode to, say, Windows 7? Or run PL/SQL Developer as administrator? BTW yes, I'm *Hrvat* (Croatian) :)

Comment: So to sum up, you have a pre-made script, that creates an Oracle DB database structure and fills it with data. You've tried using PL/SQL Developer to run that script and the PL/SQL Developer application crashes on one of your Windows machines (the "application stopped responding" Windows message). Have you tried using a different application, e.g. [Oracle SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html)? Have you tried spooling the output to a file (as @Littlefoot suggested)?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the rectification, I'm on Windows 10, yes it's the same OS on the gaming computer. I already tried with compatibility mode and I also tried to run PL/SQL as administrator and It's not working.

Comment: I didn't try with another tool, the school bought us a valid license for PL/SQL so I wanted to stay on this tool.  @Hilarion

Comment: The "PL/SQL Developer" tool is free. The Oracle DB may not be, but there is a free version available. If you need that scripted DB to work with, and running the script in parts works, this should be a viable workaround. That type of scripts perform separate steps, which, in most cases, do not all need to be run in one transaction, one session nor one batch file. You just need to split it (preferably based on logical parts) and run in parts and the DB will be exactly the same, as if you successfully run the file as whole.

Comment: PL/SQL Developer is not free (bit.ly/2rdJEIf). Yes that's what I dit but I'm always searsching how to fix this problem.. I will install another Tool if I don't find a way to run the script in once. Thank you for your help !

Comment: So, you installed Oracle as well as PL/SQL developer on a gaming computer using License provided by school  and not on your Laptop?  What's the configuration of that machine compared to your laptop?

Comment: I installed PL/SQL and Oracle on both. The gamging computer has 16gb ram, CPU i7 3,8 GHz, GPU GTX1060 and 64 bits as the Laptop. @KaushikNayak

Comment: I will try to install PL/SQL in 32bits, maybe the problem will be solve.

Comment: @mariocrocop: My mistake on the PL/SQL Developer. For some reason I confused it with the "Oracle SQL Developer" tool (which is a free Oracle product). It's even more embarrassing, as I've used the "Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer" for longer, than I'm using "Oracle SQL Developer". The reason I've switched may be the same you are facing, the "Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer" seems to be developed by 1 person, so it's release cycle is quite slow so it was behind in support for new versions of Oracle DB and Windows and bugs tended to live long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found who to fix the problem on my Laptop, thank you everyone.

I just re-installed the older version of PL/SQL that I used before the update and when I launch the script, I don't touch any window of the computer, I juste waiting about 3 - 4 minutes (even if Windows say that "PL/SQL stopped responding") and then, it's just work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your PL/SQL Developer tool, not with your SQL script. It works fine on school computer but crashes on your laptop.

Options :

- split the SQL script in several, smaller parts, and execute them one by one (like : 8 x 1000 insert commands instead of 1 x 8000 insert commands)
- use another tool to run your script ; [SQLDeveloper](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sql-developer.html) may be a good alternative (it’s free and works fine on Windows)